# Toggle WIFI radio programmatically

Tags: android, wifi

Is it possible to toggle WiFi radio (On/Off) programmatically on android phones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the WifiManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Specifically:

> `boolean setWifiEnabled(boolean enabled)`
>       *Enable or disable Wi-Fi.*

Answer (score 2):

**To Enable WiFi:**

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

**Note:
To access with WiFi state, we have to add following permissions inside the AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS 
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually toggle, meaning, switching the state, use:

```
WifiManager wm = ((WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));
wm.setWifiEnabled(!wm.isWifiEnabled());
```

and add the permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS 
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
```